# Decoding image using tensorflow

Tags: image, image-processing, tensorflow

I am trying to read an image in tf. Using the image file name I perform the following simple operations.

```py
image_string = tf.read_file(imagefilename)
image = tf.image.decode_image(image_string)
```

Now, when I print image after `sess.run`, I get the values of all the indices in the tensor to be same and 254.  Any guesses where I am wrong?

Pointers on debugging would also help.

The batch processing code:

```py
def _parse_image(self,imagefile,text,label):
    image_string = tf.read_file(imagefile)
    image = tf.image.decode_image(image_string)    
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
    return image, text, label   


def get_batch(self,typefile="train",batch_size = 64, num_workers = 40):
     train_dataset = tf.contrib.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((images, text, labels)) // This works fine. the filename, text and labels are correctly loaded
     train_dataset = train_dataset.map(self._parse_image,num_threads=num_workers, output_buffer_size= batch_size)
     batched_train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(batch_size)
     return batched_train_dataset


batch_train_dataset = get_batch("train")
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
iterator = batch_train_dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
next_element = iterator.get_next()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    sess.run(iterator.initializer)
out = sess.run(next_element)
tf.Print(out)
```

When I print out, I get the text and label as fine but the images are all having the same value. Anything wrong I am doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is correct. Try to read [this image](https://github.com/chiphuyen/stanford-tensorflow-tutorials/blob/master/data/friday.jpg) with this snippet:

```py
image_string = tf.read_file('friday.jpg')
image = tf.image.decode_image(image_string)

with tf.Session() as session:
  img_value = session.run(image)
  print(np.min(img_value), np.max(img_value), np.mean(img_value))
```

.. and you should get:

```py
0 255 93.6996542494
```

... which is a reasonable distribution of image pixels.

- If you still see the array of `254`, this would be very strange, you might need to reinstall tensorflow.
- If the snippet above works for `friday.jpg`, but fails for your `imagefilename`, try to inspect the format of your image. Is it corrupted?
- If both output reasonable pixel distributions, the image is read correctly, it's just a bug in your tensor evaluation.

Comment: Thanks @Maxim. This works for my system. The tf installation is correct then. 

I am actually processing a batch of images. I will update the question with the exact code

Comment: This is good. So, if the bug is somewhere else in the code, I think you ask another question (the focus of this question is different) and provide the code snippet (may be the data as well?) so that the problem can be reproduced. I understand what you're doing, but can't say anything from this one line of code.

Comment: Sure.  Let me do it.

Comment: Hi, I tried using the image Friday.jpg in my pipeline and found the mean etc were correctly computed. Hence, thought more about it.

Basically, my images were all white background images and when I print the huge numpy array, only a portion of them is printed. Hence all of them were 254. 

Thanks a lot. I am just starting to work with images.